# Changing Presented view controller constraints

Tags: c#, ios, uiviewcontroller, constraints

I have tried to find an answer to this for a while. What I want to do is to change the constraints of a ViewController in relation with his "father".
Here is what I tried to do, but I get an error:

```
 partial void BackAction(Foundation.NSObject sender)
 {
   /// My "parent" view controller - the one that presented this view
   UIViewController ApplicationViewController = Application.GetPresentedViewController("ApplicationViewController");
   /// Here I am trying to update the constrains in relation with his father  
   View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(ApplicationViewController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 1, 30));
   /// and also let the view digest the constrains
   View.UpdateConstraints();
 }
```

When I am adding the constraints, I get this error:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  
Name: NSInvalidArgumentException 
Reason: NSLayoutConstraint for <UILayoutContainerView: 0x104903e70; frame = (0 0; 375 812); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c802ff20>>: 
A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. 
Location attributes must be specified in pairs.
```

Please help me find out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the missing view parameter.

> Create(NSObject, NSLayoutAttribute, NSLayoutRelation, NSObject,
>   NSLayoutAttribute, nfloat, nfloat)

```
View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(ApplicationViewController.View, NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin, NSLayoutRelation.Equal,View,NSLayoutAttribute.LeftMargin,1, 30));
```

Comment: Still not working, Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.

Comment: Maybe, I need to somehow initialize ( or show ) the previous viewcontroller. But still, I don't know how to show the previous viewcontroller without dismissing the current one

Comment: Are you sure that your View is inside your ApplicationViewController.View? View need to added to the father first that the constraints.

Comment: Do you need to show the previous view without dismissing the currentVC?

Comment: Yes, I do, I want to make like a swipe left to the previous view, using pan gesture

Comment: ApplicationViewController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentedViewController, this is how I initialized ApplicationViewController

Comment: Any ideas kevinosaurio ?

Comment: Yes, constraints doesn't work like you want to work. You don't have a "father". If you set it the `UIModalPresentationStyle` to `overFullScreen`. Then you can try change the frame. View.Frame = new CGRect(30, 0, View.Frame.Size.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173233/discussion-between-darius-buhai-and-kevinosaurio).